# Masas in SAW*-algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, compactness

I [asked this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057595/maximal-abelian-subalgebras-of-saw-algebras) three years ago at MSe but it has no response; let me try here.

Pedersen distilled the following class of C*-algebras which he termed SAW*-algebras ([*Journal of Operator Theory*, **15**, No. 1 (1986), 15-32.](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24714346?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)):

A C*-algebra $A$ is an *SAW*-algebra* if for each pair of orthogonal, positive elements $x,y\in A$, there exists a positive element $e\in A$ such that $ex=x$ and $(1-e)y=y$.

This looks very commutatively, hence my question:

> Let $B$ be a maximal abelian subalgebra of an SAW*-algebra. Is $B$ an SAW*-algebra?

This is the case for AW* algebras which are SAW* *a fotriori*.